# 2's complement question

Tags: twos-complement

I have a q related to 2's complement.
Say I have a signed 16 bit hexadecimal in 2's complement representation
for example, take 0xfaa

if it's 16 bit, i need to expand it cause it only has 12 bits now. I know i have to expand the left side, so it'd be made into 0xffaa.

that means that my number is negative, is that correct?

Comment: ok thanks, you're both right i think
if its a 16 bit already, then its 0x0faa because the 0 is ommited but if i need to expand it from a 12 bit to a 16 bit, its 0xffaa
thanks

Comment: @PeguinSource - Please accept the best answer.  It helps people who have the same question in the future get their answer quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make the most significant digit a 0, so it would be 0x0faa.  If you assume and f goes there you have changed the value of the number.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then you are correct.

If it's a 12-bit two's complement negative number, then you take the high-order bit -- bit 11, as it's usually called -- and copy it into all bits to its left to fill the high-order 4 bits of its 16-bit equivalent. The 12-bit value you have -- `0xfaa` -- becomes the 16-bit value `0xffaa`, just as you have said in your question.

In binary, the 12-bit value is

```
    111110101010
    ^
    +---- bit 11
```

and becomes the 16-bit value

```
 1111111110101010
 ^   ^
 |   +-------- bit 11 
 +------------ bit 15
```

That the two words are of different lengths in no way changes the fact that the two numbers are equal.